Android contacts tags not saved or exported
On android 11 onward contacts has way to add label and its "add tags" in the latest android 14 but i noticed that when these contacts are saved or exported as csv they do not have any "tag" info in .csv. Is this is a bug or am i missing some other ways to save all the contact info including tags?
